# Dirichlet series with an abscissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_{0}$, analytic in $\sigma > \sigma_{0} - \delta$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, dirichlet-series

Suppose that a Dirichlet series $f(s)$ has the abscissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_{0}$ and is analytic in $\sigma > \sigma_{0} - \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. For $\sigma > \sigma_{0}$, it is easy to see that
\[
f(\sigma + it) \ll 1.
\]

Now, with these conditions specific to Dirichlet series and with some other standard techniques of complex analysis (or with any other sophisticated techniques), can we prove that there exists an $A > 0$ such that
\[
f(\sigma + it) \ll |t|^{A}, \quad \sigma > \sigma_{0} - \delta \quad ?
\]

If of any help, you could use another condition that 
\[
f(\sigma + it) \ll e^{|t|^{\alpha}}, \quad \alpha < 1, \quad \sigma > \sigma_{0} - \delta.
\]

Or, can you make a counterexample?

Comment: If you are asking about in the half-plane of (conditional) convergence, then see 9.33 of Titchmarsh. https://archive.org/stream/TheTheoryOfFunctions/Titchmarsh-TheTheoryOfFunctions#page/n305/mode/2up
If not, can't you just exponentiate something like the $L$-series of the Dirichlet character of conductor 4? This is still a Dirichlet series, and it has an entire continuation, and routinely it grows faster than you like vertically. You can of course iteratively exponentiate....

Comment: Yes. Exponentiation of any well-known appropriate Dirichlet series, even that of the Riemann zeta-function, just gives me a counterexample.